# Applicant requested substantially higher salary than I had in mind: is it worth negotiating?

Tags: salary, hiring

I recently interviewed an applicant.  At the end of the interview I asked him what he was looking for in terms of salary.

The number he gave was substantially higher than what I had in mind (about 50% higher).  I did some research to make sure that my salary expectations for the job and in my specific area were reasonable, and I'm very confident that they are.

Presuming that the candidate would otherwise be a good fit, is it worth to negotiate?

With such a large difference in salary expectations I feel like there isn't any way that we are both going to end up happy, but I'm relatively new to hiring and uncertain about a definitive answer.  Could there be more to the story here that I am missing?

---

Having read all this advice and having had more time to reflect upon the interview, here are some more details that might be relevant:

We advertised a position for a full stack engineer and he emailed us directly with his resume as a front-end HTML/CSS developer. He understood the fact that he was not the candidate we were asking for in our job posting, but we have a variety of needs (including an expert in those skills), so we interviewed him anyway. As a result, there was no stated salary expectations (although his asking salary is at the high end of the posted engineer salary range).

It sounds like at his current job he has a wide variety of different responsibilities. However, he billed himself to us as a front end HTML/CSS person, which is the skill set I was interested in. His other skills aren't of real value to us, and other skills that would make him more valuable to us are things that he doesn't have. As a result, his value to us is largely driven by his experience as an HTML/CSS developer.  It could be that he might be worth more to other companies that might give him broader responsibilities.

Comment: It's completely normal.  Just say "I can offer you X"  Nothing more to it.  Everyone always starts "far higher, far lower" on each end.  Don't make a big fuss, at all, about the 50% aspect. Don't even mention the 50% aspect.  Just state "we can offer you X".  It's a non-issue, 50% is nothing in a negotiation.  (If the person ends up going somewhere else, good luck to them, right?)  Bottom line: it's commonplace to have such differences in a salary negotiation.

Comment: You may want to make sure you both mean the same thing by "salary". It sounds like you take it to mean "wages" and he may mean "total compensation package, including benefits." Get on the same page first - then decide whether or not it's worth pursuing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60584/discussion-on-question-by-conor-mancone-applicant-requested-substantially-higher).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> Presuming that the candidate would otherwise be a good fit, is it worth to negotiate?

If you don't negotiate, you definitely won't hire him (because he's asking too much) and therefore you're left without an employee.

If you DO negotiate (even if "negotiating" is just "look, I can offer you X, take it or leave it") then you MIGHT get an employee in the end.  You might also not, but that really just leaves you where you would've been anyway - meaning you haven't *lost anything* in making the attempt.

It seems to me the only real question to ask is "can I negotiate for something in between my value and his (and how high can I go), or do I need to stand firm?"  That's a question best asked of your own boss, if you don't already know the answer.  Then, go back to the candidate and make him your best offer.

Que sera, sera.

Comment: OP could end up with an employee who jumps ship too soon. That's worse than not hiring at all.

Comment: If the candidate **agrees to negotiate**, *accepts the offer of a lower price* and then proceeds to jump ship because "he's not getting paid enough," that's the candidate operating in bad faith.  Apart from watching for red flags during the interview itself, I'm not sure what the interviewer can do to avoid those sorts of shenanigans.

Comment: In fact, if the candidate is inclined to jump ship immediately because he gets a better offer elsewhere, he'd probably be inclined to do that anyway **even if the OP gave him the salary he requested.**  If someplace else offers him 10% more, he's gone.

Comment: Agree with Steve-O completely, but I would also add in @sleddog's comment above that you need to make sure you're explaining the total compensation correctly.  Many candidates (especially if they're relatively new to the game or haven't experienced a truly awful job that pays well but otherwise ruins their work/life balance or leaves them without medical insurance) make the mistake of looking only at wages.

Comment: Maybe the candidate might act in bad faith, maybe they might decide that it's worth working for less money because of the location/team/work/whatever, maybe they might delude themselves it's worth working for less but then later realize the delusion. I am not saying "don't negotiate," just that you need to explore the reason for the difference in expectations just as much as you need to agree on a salary.

Comment: @stannius Is it? You're paying the employee to provide a service you need done. If you need the work done, and someone's willing to do it, hire the person. Employers don't lose value when they pay for labour and receive it.

Comment: @JaguarWong Yes, it can be worse: in many jobs, there's a steep enough learning curve that you can't really contribute fully for a while, so an employee who quits before they get past that period doesn't actually provide much value. Sometimes hiring is an investment, not just a daily purchase of labor.

Comment: @Steve-O Calling this bad faith is a bit strong. Just because you accept a given salary doesn't mean you're obligated to reject all future job offers. Barring a contract, leaving a job for a higher paying one is just career progression. Nobody applies for just one job, and a better offer can come along after accepting one. It happens and it's not malicious, just inconvenient.

Comment: @Steve-O But if you pay him what he asks, the chance that another place will pay 10% over that will be greatly reduced.

Comment: @Jefromi: You can handle that by offering an annual bonus.

Comment: @MSalters That may save a bit of money, and discourage some people from joining and quitting, but it doesn't really handle it. There's still plenty of wasted time and money and delay if someone stays a couple months and quits despite the prospect of the bonus.

Comment: @MSalters Even a guaranteed bonus will still discourage those seeking the higher wage _now_.

Answer (score 43):

Negotiating on salary is actually an important part of hiring process - not only for obvious reasons but also because you can find something about the person you are considering to hire.

The best option would be to be frank and ask: "The salary you've requested is bigger than I've anticipated for this role. While it's perfectly normal, I'd like to know more about your reasoning behind this".

There's whole palette of possible answers that will potentially help you see candidate under different angle. Even if you are 100% sure that it's not negotiable, at least you'll know more.

Comment: I like the idea that a candidates handling of this situation is also another window into their qualities as an employee.

Comment: This might be unfair. The common advice is to start high and work down, because you anticipate the other guy to start down and work up. But now you're suddenly asking him why he started high. Who's going to tell you the obvious truth to your face -- that they started high because expected you to start low, because that's how negotiations work? You're effectively coercing him into lying. If you're really so confident that your existing employees would tell you the honest truth to your face, then go for it. Otherwise, if he lies, it's more a reflection on you than him.

Comment: @Mehrdad Whether he lies or not is part of the information you get. Nobody said interviews were fair.

Comment: @immibis: I mean, if you want to deliberately make the interview unfair and be a jerk by forcing someone to lie, then go ahead. I'm not crying for the other guy, I'm just making it clear that that's what you'd be doing.

Comment: @Mehrdad you've used term "unfair" twice already and I'm still having hard times to understand what exactly you find unfair. Asking candidate to provide some explanations on his salary expectations?

Comment: @Mehrdad That already happens...

Comment: @shabunc: Putting someone into a position where they have to either (a) dodge the question (and therefore potentially shoot themselves in the foot interview-wise), (b) insult you (by suggesting you're the kind to low-ball them), or (c) lie to you in order to save both your faces, is what I'm calling unfair. It's not exactly equivalent obviously, but it's similar to entrapment. And there's a reason why that's considered an invalid interrogation method. Because it makes mostly-honest people do things they wouldn't normally do.

Comment: @Mehrdad I completely disagree, there're  lot of other options on the plate here. It's completely OK to ask a bigger salary and it's completely normal to expect someone being able to explain why. It looks like we have a different understanding of what unfair is but that just happened.

Comment: @shabunc: What would you expect someone who started high just because they expected you to start low to tell you? And would you reply the same way in that situation? And would your existing employees?

Comment: @Mehrdad I've negotiated about salary like all we did and always was completely fine with any questions of this kind. For starters, I'd never tried play high, I just named the figure is relevant to my current set of skills regarding the situation at the market at the moment.

I've never treated this as if I'm forced to lie or insult anyone btw.

Comment: @Mehrdad What would you say if you started high because you expected someone to start low, and someone asked you that question? What would you say if you *didn't* deliberately start high and someone asked you that question? What if you even started low and they asked you that question?

Comment: @shabunc: Well that's my point, some people start high because that's the advice people give them (like on these forums), and they're don't know better. I'm not asking what *you* do. I'm asking, what do you expect *them* to do to save face? What would you do in *their* shoes?

Comment: @immibis: If I didn't start high or low I'd just say it's because my impression is this is a fair salary, taking into account the market rate and my own needs. I obviously can't say that in the other two cases. But I don't get your point. Instead of getting clever and reflecting my question back at me maybe tell me what your own answer is first.

Comment: @Mehrdad nobody tries to convince you in anything. You've raised your concerns and got some feedback. That's basically it. It's OK to have a different point of view. Perhaps you can live your own answer. It's just not constructive.

Comment: Wrong advice, you just anchored around 50% more and are going to be in a long conversation about whether you will pay 20% or 30% more in the near future.

Answer (score 12):

I would have to respectfully disagree with the other comments and answers if you are looking for a long term employee.  If you are looking to fill a hole quickly, then maybe I would make an offer.  If I were looking long term, the fact is that this person is most likely to be unhappy working for you and will be putting in time while looking for another job.  In the end you waste all the resources that go into training / getting up to speed.  In the long run if that person thinks they are worth 50% more than you offer they wont want to stay long term.

50% is a big number.  If he is going high to negotiate, he must really be wanting at least 20% or so more than your offer.

ps  I would take one more look at your research into what the local market is paying for those skills.  If his skills are in high demand, it may be that he really is worth much more than you planned to offer for the position.

Comment: That's my concern.  I'm still very confused about the discrepancy.  He seemed very confident that what he was asking was reasonable, and I'm still fairly certain that it was way off.  I ended up turning him down as a candidate without further negotiations because of some additional reasons.  However, we have more hiring to do in the next month or so, so I figured I might as well ask as many questions as I can now :)

Comment: @ConorMancone - I am not confused by the discrepancy, assuming I have correctly understood your comments on the question. He applied for a role (role 1), which had in its advert a salary of up to 3X. He therefore stated his salary expectation was 3X. You interviewed him thinking of putting him in a completely different role, role 2, which you would only expect to pay 2X for. I assume he thought he was interviewing for role 1, or equivalent seniority in role 2, and therefore expected the advertised salary.

Comment: This answer boils down to "this employer should be paying 50% more than the market rate," and I'm not sure why this employer is not part of the market. Because they want a hire quickly? I can't really imagine a firm in a job market wanting a hire slowly.

Comment: As for your last stanza it's really on the employee's burden to explain why he didn't just make up a number. And I strongly recommend *not* asking since you don't want to frame around an unproven high number. If he doesn't volunteer justification he's probably full of it.

Comment: @djechlin You can't imagine any situation in which hiring ASAP for an immediate need, and taking your time to hire the best person you can at a reasonable rate, are at odds?

Comment: @MatthewRead I actually can't imagine any situation where they're not, but I don't know your point.

Comment: @djechlin I may have worded my answer badly.  What it should boil down to is that I feel a hiring manager should not bother to negotiate if the employee feels that they are worth 50% more than you think the market is paying as they will never be happy.  I threw in an exception for when you urgently need to fill a hole(s), say if several very key people leave and there is an immediate need to fill those positions as fast as possible.

Comment: @Joe hiring in knowledge jobs tends to go like, "hire the fastest person you can, who is at least X good, where X is pretty high." there's not really any way to speed up the basic math on that. A fast, poor-quality hire is not a quadrant any hiring manager winds up in more than once in their life. So this is where I disagree with your answer, "fill a hole quickly" is just not a real use case, and if the OP gets the idea it is they will make grave errors.

Comment: @djechlin Two of the positions I have held over the years have been in fast paced environments with rock solid deadlines.  One example is elections, you cant be late, period.  If you have a hole you can hire qualified people who can start getting work done immediately if properly managed.  So, I still hold to what I said.  That being that there are exceptions to my suggested approach.

Answer (score 3):

You negotiate by simply declining to giving the candidate an offer at that price. What you don't do is negotiate *poorly*, which means letting the candidate frame the conversation at an out-of-band number, and that would surely happen if you open yourself up to having to explain what's wrong with their number.

> "I'm sorry but we don't offer that compensation, good luck in your search."

Is about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you press him to give a number?  If you did he could be following the advice of a book that I recently read on negotiation.  There the author specifically says to give an unrealistic number when forced to give one.  Then a person, in your position will say "wow, I can't do that".  Essentially closing the "sale", now it is just a mater of price (salary in this case).  You are probably considering raising the amount you were willing to pay for the position.

I'd talk to the candidate.  You will have to make sure of two things:  First he can afford to live on the number he is giving.  There may be other reasons why he is asking for a high salary, perhaps personal reasons dictate how much salary he can accept.  You do not want to hire someone who cannot afford to live.

Second is that he will be happy at the agreed upon amount.  You don't want to hire someone who is cranky about the salary they accepted even though it was their choice.

It is always worth it to have a conversation to see where a negotiation could go.

The book is *Never Split the Difference: Negotiating As If Your Life Depended On It*, and a fun read for non-fiction.

Comment: Meh. If the author of that book is such an amazing negotiator, why aren't they out negotiating and doing awesome deals instead of writing books about it? By requesting an unrealistic salary, the candidate has come very close to removing themself from consideration for the job. That sounds like a lousy plan, "if your life depended on it."

Comment: Well the author was a hostage negotiator for the FBI; and, currently owns a consulting firm that specializes on the subject.  He certainly new more about the subject than most people I know.

Comment: I'm failing to see the applicability. In a hostage situation, it's the hostage taker who's making demands. So he's advising them to make unrealistic demands to get more concessions from the FBI?